Comedy about twins where one is the president and the other is in an asylum
I watched this movie on TV in late 90s or at very least early 00s, so I'm pretty sure it was made in 90s, or maybe in 80s, but I doubt.
This is not that movie with Arnie!
There were two male twins (played by the same actor), and one of them was left near some door, orphan's home I guess, by his parents. So one of them, who wasn't abandoned, became a president, the other one got in asylum (I can mistake about asylum, but he was crazy, that is for sure). I remember the scene where crazy one rolled out from asylum/hospital on gurney through the window on 2nd floor or so. I also remember that crazy one had imaginary friends in some closet.
The main actor (or character) reminds Jim Carrey somehow, but it was long ago so I can err.

By 'president' do you mean the US President?

@Walt, I guess so, at least I remember like that.

@Necronomicron were the twins both male? Are they identical i.e played by the same actor?

@tohood87, yes and yes.

You're looking for The Nutt House from 1992.

Identical twins Philbert and Nathan were separated at birth. Philbert is married to a wealthy heiress (Amy Yasbeck) with a mistress (Traci Lords) and a political campaign for President of the United States. Nathan suffers from a severe case of multiple personality disorder and has spent his life in a lunatic asylum. Nathan shows up on his brother's doorstep and what begins as a case of mistaken identity spirals out of control.

It was co-written by Sam Raimi, his brother Ivan and Bruce Campbell (!!), who were so embarrassed with the result that they went by Alan Smithee. Here's the trailer, where you can see the gurney scene (Warning: Wackiness Overload):




Incidentally, some of these scenes are really reminiscent of The Mask (which also starred Yasbeck). I'd call rip-off, but it actually preceded it.
